# Custom CSS With SquareSpace

Tags: css, hover, effect, squarespace

I am trying to add custom CSS to my Squarespace page. When a user hovers over an image I want it to change opacity, but only if there is an URL link associated with the image. Currently, my below code is causing all images on my site to change opacity. Any help would be great!

custom CSS :    .sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide:hover {opacity:.6 !important;}

```
 <div class="sqs-gallery">

            <div class="slide" data-type="image">
              <div class="margin-wrapper">
                <a


                        href="/umma" 



                  class="image-slide-anchor content-fit"
                >
                  <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51eb1fb3e4b0ca0d358f4e39/58b4538be4fcb5c5e088f247/58b454483a04111160e30ab0/1488228183093/logo.png"  alt="UX Research"  /></noscript><img class="thumb-image" alt="UX Research" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51eb1fb3e4b0ca0d358f4e39/58b4538be4fcb5c5e088f247/58b454483a04111160e30ab0/1488228183093/logo.png" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51eb1fb3e4b0ca0d358f4e39/58b4538be4fcb5c5e088f247/58b454483a04111160e30ab0/1488228183093/logo.png" data-image-dimensions="266x125" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="58b454483a04111160e30ab0" data-type="image" />
                </a>
                  <div class="image-slide-title">UX Research</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slide" data-type="image">
              <div class="margin-wrapper">
                <a


  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: `a .sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide:hover {opacity:.6 !important;}`?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I added my HTML to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `a` selector before the class name which, I'm assuming, refers to the image. Like this:

```
a .sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide:hover {
    opacity: .6 !important;
}
```

This will work for all images that are wrapped within `a` tags.

You could go even further and limit it to only links that redirect to URLs by using the `^=` attribute CSS selector. This is used to select only elements whose attribute value begins with a given string e.g. `http` (for links). Like this:

```
a[href^=http] .sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide:hover {
    opacity: .6 !important;
}
```

**EDIT (to take into account editing of question):**

Use this code:

```
.image-slide-anchor img:hover {
      opacity: .6 !important;
}
```

**EDIT 2 (to take into account asker's comment):**

OK, the working solution is to change `image-slide-anchor img:hover` to `a.image-slide-anchor[href] img:hover`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried all three of your suggestions. The last one still causes images that do not have an URL link to also change opacity, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the URL of your website? The class you mention in your question is not found in the code that you've pasted

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine to me. Can you be more specific as to which images exactly you want to fade on hover?

Comment: Sure on the cover page if you scroll down there are 3 images( tiles: called UMMA, Centro, Ceramic Work), that link to another page on my site. I want those images to change opacity when you hover over them. This is currently happening, but also if you click on the first image called UMMA it takes you to another page that has other images without links. Those images are also changing opacity( I do NOT want this to happen).

Comment: So update I did a little more research and with SquareSpace you have to invoke a collections ID that each page has. Based in this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0AR09lDi8M  So I tried to use the collections id, just for the coverpage....but the opacity is still affecting images that are not on the cover page.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Change `image-slide-anchor img:hover` to `a.image-slide-anchor[href] img:hover`. The images on the other page are also wrapped within links BUT they do not contain the `href` attribute. The code above checks for that and only applies the hover effect IF the link has the `href` attribute i.e. it is a link that leads somewhere.

Comment: Additionally, you may have anchor tags whose `href` attribute begins with `#` or some Javascript code and you don't want the hover effect on images contained within them. To tailor for that, use the attribute selector `^=` included in my original answer, which checks if the attribute value begins with certain characters.

Comment: Awesome thanks do much for the help! That worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information